# get specific value from array in indexpath.row

Tags: arrays, swift

i am trying to get the second and third value from car make array and return in on function below. i have tried 
`cell.title.text = carmake[1...2][indexPath.row]` and `cell.title.text = carmake[indexPath.[1...2]]` but none of them are correct. please help me

```
carmake = ["hi","hello","how are you","i am good"]

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = viewcontrol.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! jobtypeCollectionViewCell

  cell.title.text = carmake[indexPath.row]
  return cell
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear (at least to me). How many items has the collection  view, and what should the title of each item be?

Comment: the collection view should have 2 items from carmake array, the cell title should be = "hello","how are you".  there are 4 value in carmake array but i only want to get 2 values out of 4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine them, you can try:

```
cell.title.text = carmake[1] + carmake[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return just the second and third items from your array in a collectionview, this is what you should try:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //returns number of sections in collectionview, which in your case seems to be 1
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    //returns number of items per section, which in your case, you have stated is 1
    return 1

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = viewcontrol.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! jobtypeCollectionViewCell
    //indexpath.item starts at 0. indexPath.item + 1 and + 2 because you want to return carMake[1] and carMake[2].
    cell.title.text = carmake[indexPath.item + 1] + carmake[indexPath.item + 2]

    return cell
}
```